# power bi Matrix visualization

Tags: powerbi

Table:
[image: Table]

Matrix:
[image: Matrix]

Hello, I Have the same problem, but when I changed to Matrix visualization, it only shows on column, and not all columns as the table visualization,  the problem with the table visualization is that  it shows duplicated data. Any idea how can I show data in matrix (without duplicates) in the same column order as a table?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

For reference, my table looks like this...

[image: Table]

... and my matrix looks like this.

[image: Matrix Starter]

On the matrix, you want to click on the forked drill down arrow until all fields are showing.

[image: Drill down]

Which results in something like this.

[image: Drilled Matrix]

From here, open the format section (the paint roller icon below the visualization pane), expand Row Headers, and turn Stepped layout to off.

[image: Matrix Options]

This gives you a matrix that looks like this.

[image: Final Matrix]